# "Inherent in" vs "inherent to."

Tags: prepositions, phrase-choice

I thought the phrase was "[inherent in,](https://www.google.com.tw/search?ei=GUC_W-XICYyC8gWxhqHQAg&q=%22inherent%20in%20people%20who%22&oq=%22inherent%20in%20people%20who%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1293.1730.0.1883.6.6.0.0.0.0.122.430.4j2.6.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.0.0....0.I9lJ9n3YimE)" but then I found out that [inherent to](https://www.google.com.tw/search?ei=G0C_W8WbG4SY8gW1tIWICA&q=%22inherent%20to%20people%20who%22&oq=%22inherent%20to%20people%20who%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...71416.71680.0.71879.2.2.0.0.0.0.46.84.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.EWCedNrPL8I) is also used.

Do they mean the same thing? Or do they have slightly different meanings?

Example sentence:

> They shared that comfortable silence inherent in/to couples who no longer need to impress each other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The preposition **to** can express a possessive relationship.

> Where is the key **to** this lock?

The key that *belongs to* or *belongs with* this lock.

In your sentence, **to** works well because "couples" are entities, as a lock is an entity.  The silence is "theirs" to share. It is not an intrinsic characteristic of them.

We use **inherent in** when referring to intrinsic characteristics of situations more abstract  than "couples":

> There is risk inherent in any investment.

Comment: Thank you for this, very well explained.

Answer (score 0):

They shared that comfortable silence inherent in/to couples who no longer need to impress each other.

preposition and verb:

They shared that comfortable silence existing between couples who no longer need to impress each other.

Generally, one says there is **silence between two people**. And I find it quite odd to say that a silence is inherent, unless you say it is inherent in the relationship between two people, which would give us:

They shared that comfortable silence **inherent in a relationship** between couples who no longer need to impress each other.

As we say **in a relationship** here, I would use inherent followed by **in** due to the phrase "in a relationship".

If the phrase as had been to the relationship or something else with to, I would have used "inherent to [doing some activity].